# nvidia-settings not showing all options

Tags: nvidia-settings

all. I am having issues related to the program **nvidia-settings**

My system is a Lenovo Y410P with the GK107M/GT750M GPU. I am running 14.04 Ubuntu.

When I start nvidia-settings through the terminal, the GUI only shows the **Application Profiles** and **nvidia-settings Configuration** options on the left.

In the terminal, after starting the application it reads:

> **Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
>   **Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

I purged the nvidia-304, and re-installed the nvidia-331. Under Additional drivers I am using the 331.113 from nvidia-331.

nvidia-settings version is 331.20

Any help would be much appreciated.
All I'm trying to do is stop video tearing during movie playback.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is missing this: NV-CONTROL package,...I found this info... since nvidia-settings Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
 The nvidia-settings utility is a tool for configuring the NVIDIA
 Linux graphics driver.  It operates by communicating with the NVIDIA
 X driver, querying and updating state as appropriate.  This
 communication is done with the NV-CONTROL X extension....